# Why would Chrome randomly go back multiple pages?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, macros

*My browser just jumps back several pages.*

**Other issues:**

- Cannot click in task bar while in any window.
- Cannot click inside a window if it is brought up from the task bar
  (only alt-tabbing into a program works).
- Cannot click on the task bar when Windows starts.
- Cannot click on a start menu item after pressing the start key after
  windows starts.
- Cannot click on other windows from a windowed window (In other words, there's no way to escape a window by mouse click.  You must click win+d, click minimize, or use alt+tab.).

**Minor work-arounds (reduces some of the behaviors):**

- Turn off all non-Microsoft services and restart the system.  Chrome
  still randomly jumps back, leading me to believe there may be two
  separate issues.
- Right-click each program and select 'run as administrator'. 
  Sometimes, this resolves some issues.

**Additional info**

- This happens when I left-click inside Chrome.

**Inspected causes**

- Keytweak.  My only macroing software.  Disabled.  Removed all keys.
- Add-ons.  Disabled all.
- Non-Microsoft services.  Disabled all.
- I thought: it could be a macro program sending keys.  But then, why is it only a problem in Chrome?

Comment: Have you checked whether the moue button might be faulty. It could be faulty in such a way that it often doesn't register, or registers as a double click. What kind of pointing device are you using? Have you tried a different one?

Comment: @nitro2k0 For some reason, I think that might be the case.  I've had trouble with the built-in mouse buttons.  I can't disable them, even via the BIOS.  It sucks. :>

Comment: If it's a Synaptics brand touchpad, you should be able to configure it well after installing the driver. Otherwise, you could try to find in the Windows device manager and disable the whole device, which may or may not be convenient for you.

Comment: @nitro2k01 It is Synaptics.  But in the config, even with it disabled, the buttons work.  Disabling it just disables the pad.

Comment: What did you disable? If the device in the device manager, are there any additional devices in the mouse category? If in the control panel, I'm seeing this: http://i.imgur.com/kZVQmgB.png I can disable "tapping" or "buttons" but not both at the same time it seems. Try disabling one at a time and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @nitro2k01 None of that is available to me.  I can't disable the driver, either.  I think, actually, it's only disabled in the BIOS.  I can turn off 'tap to click', and I can turn it off in the bios.

Comment: I think it's someone just playing around with my PC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We should make this a wiki page.

The problem is: I used tape to repair the mouse (months prior), and it was holding down a mouse button that I did not know existed.  Updating the drivers enabled the mouse buttons.  This mouse button's default action is to go back in browsers.

[image: Thought it was an elite hacker.]

Comment: In case you're wondering: yes, that's mouse 4.